# how to get the configuration class code of hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get the code of `hibernate.cfg.Configuration` class code.. I mean the full java code of `Configuration` class .. how can i get that ?

Comment: i agree with the downvote.. but atleast tell me if i can get the code or not !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. View it online: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.java.html
2. Get it from GitHub: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm
3. Clone the repo: git clone git://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm.git
4. If you already use maven: use -DdownloadSources to get the sources for artifacts

There are a lot of better and easier ways then decompiling the class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay .. ! so i figured it out some how .. you need to download a java decompiler. .. you can get one here: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/